# "За душой"

Tags: фразеология

Говорят, "у меня за душой нет ни гроша". А почему "за душой"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Душой (кроме всего прочего) называли углубление между ключицами, ямочку на шее над грудной костью, где, по народным поверьям, помещалась душа человека (поэтому душа нараспашку). В этом же месте на груди ("за душой") был обычай хранить деньги (в кошельке на шнурке). Когда денег нет, говорят: *за душой нет ни копейки (ни гроша, ничего)*. (Историко-этимологический словарь "Русская фразеология" А.К. Бириха и др.)

Comment: Ох уж этот Бирих...
Ну как могло малоизвестное значение (даже если оно существовало) положить начало столь распространённому обороту?

Comment: Почему тогда "за"? Кошелек-то окажется перед ямкой, т.е. "перед душой"

Answer (score 2):

"Душа" - обычная дореволюционная форма вместо "человек, люди", не только счетная ("едоков - пять душ", "мертвые души" и проч.) "За душой" = "за человеком (числится то-то и то-то)". Хотя такое выражение вполне могло восприниматься и развернуто. По аналогии например "за душой такие-то грехи".

Вообще в полной форме эта поговорка (присказка?) звучит как "За душою ни гроша - значит, чистая душа". тут душа выступает номителем не только личностного "иммущества", но и вполне материального.

~~~~

> (Историко-этимологический словарь "Русская фразеология" А.К. Бириха и др.)

Ох уж этот Бирих... Постоянно ловлю его на домыслах.
Ну как могло малоизвестное значение (даже если оно существовало) положить начало столь распространённому обороту?! К тому же оно совершенно не объясняет предлога "за".  
Если уж исходить из этой версии, то "душа" - это воротник, т.н. "душегрейка", вот он-то и был "нараспашку". И деньги хранили не в "ямочке", а **за (т.е. под) воротником**.
Другое дело, что на самом деле денежный мешочек всегда был на длинной веревке и распологался ниже нательного креста, грубо говоря - на брюхе, а не на шее. Поэтому даже такая версия сомнительна.

~~~~ 22.08

Я даже больше скажу. Скорее всего эта шейная "душа" ни с ямочкой, ни тем более со вместилищем известной нематериальной субстанции вообще никак не связана, а родственна словам **дуть, душить, дыхание**.  Душа здесь,  видимо, то, чем дышат, т.е. шея.

Comment: Вообще-то Бирих в данном случае дает ссылку на Шанского. А это известный специалист в области этимологии.

Comment: От смешного до великого - один шаг.  
Остаётся думать, что этимология фразеологизмов это совершенно отдельная область, здесь мало быть специалистом-филологом, надо еще и очень хорошо разбираться в реалиях быта прошлых веков...

Comment: Да, этимология фразеологизмов - совершенно особая область филологии. Чтобы быть значимой фигурой в этой сфере, надо быть и историком, и культурологом, хорошо знать литературу и много чего еще :-)))

Comment: И это все - о нем? :)